# Confusion about Lagrangian equation of Motion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, vectors, relativity

I am reading a book about tensor analysis. I stumbled upon the starting of the Lagrangian equations of motion. It said in the first lines....

$$ T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ can be written as $$T=\frac{m}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^3g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}.$$

Can someone explain me how the velocity equals to that?

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm not sure if the summation limit edit was justified.  We need not be in 3+1 dimensions to define kinetic energy this way.

Comment: @user143410: True, but I'm trying to make the question concrete. The generalization to other dimensions is hopefully obvious.

Comment: In the book, they might be considering n dimensions . And everything is written in Einstein's summation convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note the velocity is defined via $\vec{v}\equiv d\vec{x}/dt$.

Next note that in the expression $T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ you have smuggled in a definition of the "inner product", \begin{align}v^2 \equiv \vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}.\tag{*}\label{inner}\end{align}

Using indices to denote the components of a vector, $\vec{v}=v^i$, we could just as well express \eqref{inner} as

\begin{align}
v^2=\sum_{i}(v^i)^2=\sum_{i,j}\delta_{ij}v^iv^j=\sum_{i,j}\delta_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt},\tag{**}\label{generalized}
\end{align}
where $\delta_{ij}=1$ when $i=j$, but is zero otherwise.

Now, in some contexts (for example general relativity), it is useful to generalize \eqref{generalized} by replacing $\delta_{ij}\to g_{ij}$, where $g_{ij}$ now *defines* the inner product of vectors.  If you would like to learn more about how this works in general relativity, you should look up the "metric tensor".

Comment: Understood it. but how did the Kronecker delta come in the 2nd equation ?

Comment: I don't know what I can say differently.  Working backwards, the Kronecker delta is only nonzero when $i=j$, so if you do the sum over $j$ you'll find $\sum_{ij} \delta_{ij}v^i v^j=\sum_{i}v^iv^i$, which is precisely what is in $(**)$ reading right to left.